# Is the relation a function?

Tags: functions, relations

Is the relation on $\Bbb {R}$ a function from $\Bbb {R}$ to $\Bbb {R}$?

$$\{(a^2,a)\mid a \in \Bbb {R}\}$$

How do I determine whether or not the relation is a funtion? Would I treat $(a^2,a)$ as $(x,y)$?

Comment: Normally the argument of the function is the first element and the function value the second element. If you are unsure what is meant then you could just consider both cases, i.e. both $(x,y(x)) = (a^2, a)$ and $(y(x),x) = (a^2, a)$. One of these defines a function, the other does not. The hint: a function must be uniquely defined!

Answer (score 2):

If relation $R$ is a function then $(a,b)\in R\wedge (a,c)\in R$ implies that $b=c$.

This is not the case for $R:=\{(a^2,a)|a\in\mathbb R\}$.

For instance we have $(4,2)\in R$ and $(4,-2)\in R$ while $2\neq-2$.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if you consider $-1$ and $1$, you get $$(1,1)=(1^2,1)\in R$$ as well as $$(1,-1)=((-1)^2,-1)\in R$$

Where R is the relation you defined.

Thus, your relation gives two values for one argument at a certain point which is invalid for a function.

This would indeed *not* be the case if you switched the positions: The relation $\{(a,a^2)|a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ *is* a valid function.